# MySQL (or PHP?) group results by fields data

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL (or PHP?)  group results by field data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638952/mysql-or-php-group-results-by-field-data)

Guys, I have a database (mysql) similar to this now:

```
ID    meta_key  meta_value   name

1       _group     1          John
2       _group     1          Andrea
3       _group     1          Jack
4       _group     2          Mike
5       _group     2          Kurt
6       _group     3          Alice
```

and I need to sort / display it like this:

```
group       name
-----------------------
  1         John
            Andrea
            Jack
-----------------------
  2         Mike
            Kurt
-----------------------
  3         Alice
-----------------------
```

I had a similar issue before, thanks for the previus help! But now i'm stucked with this.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What part of doing this are you having trouble with?

Comment: And where does it differ from your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638952/mysql-or-php-group-results-by-field-data ?

Comment: Should have checked the previous question before posting the answer =\

Answer (score 0):

The display portion you could do with PHP:

```
$display = "Group\tName";
$old_group = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     if ($row['meta_value'] != $old_group) {
         $old_group = $row['meta_value'];
         $display .= "----------------------------\n" . $row['group'];
     }

     $display .= "\t" . $row['name'] . "\n";
}

echo "<pre>" . $display . "</pre>";
```

Untested, but pending any minor errors should display it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean whether to group in your mysql query or later using PHP? Then do with Mysql, that would remove your headache to write PHP code to group and sort again. In case, you need to add more sortable columns later, mysql sorting will very easily do that whereas more logic may be needed for doing with PHP

Comment: Guys i get it to work with the help of armonge, i'v just had to change the sql to 
SELECT p.meta_key as 'meta_key', p.meta_value as 'meta_value', GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names FROM prueba p WHERE p.meta_key = '_numero' GROUP BY p.meta_value

Thanks!!