# How to display groups of values using mySQL and PHP without multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the query I use to show the users and number of visits from mySQL using PHP that have equal or more than 2 visits:

```
SELECT `token`, `visits`, `id` FROM `general` where `visits` >='2' ORDER BY `visits` DESC

Tokens with more than 2 visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
```

My question is how can I show effectively in groups the token and how many visits (in number) like below ? By effectively I mean not to (if possible) have multiple queries for each group like `5 > visits < 3` and another one `visits = 2`

**Here is a demonstration:**

```
Tokens with 2 visits only
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits

Tokens with 3 to 5 visits only
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits

Tokens with 6 to 10 visits only
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits

Tokens with more than 10 visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
token number_of_visits
```

**Sample data for the 2 visits only**

```
224e4b689a032437c9dac980813e7337(2)
6d5a68ac59263a6e17624cbcfc652a2c(2)
70fd62a88a447d84869ee8104d3befe4(2)
9280791db1d2b1679d63b9d0c9231208(2)
```

Thank you

Comment: Will you know the maximum number and the ranges of all your groups ahead of time?

Comment: Show some sample data,your 'diagrams' look confusing.

Comment: Please stop deleting questions you already asked and opening them again – you already got feedback on your first question, but you are obviously ignoring it … who do you think wants to actually help you under such conditions?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, it will be fixed value ranges

Comment: @Mihai I have added a sample data for the 2 visits only

Comment: @CBroe it is a different question, more developed with different goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL (or PHP?) group results by field data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638952/mysql-or-php-group-results-by-field-data)

Comment: @Fataoulas I didn't see the first one, but if you deleted it, it's probably the same question.

Comment: @Adelphia but on the other hand, probably it didn't need to take any attention on a question I would not find use...

Comment: @Fataoulas The point of SO is to help everyone by making the solutions public. The only reason to delete the question is if you're going to ask it again in another way.

Comment: @Adelphia exactly what i did then

Answer (score 0):

you can extract it all and then [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) it. After that you can just use some for loop and some ifs to display it in blocks